# Will strace watch system calls recursively on child processes of the main process being observed?

Tags: linux, strace

If I run `strace` on a program and that program spawns a subprocess (e.g. perl's system() call), will `strace` report the system calls for the child process as well?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yes, but you need to add the `-f` flag to trace the child processes.

Comment: It's worth noting that if you are attaching strace to an already running process any _existing_ child processes are not traced even with `-f`